# meaning of "Jumping right in"

Tags: meaning

[From the Merriam-Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jump%20in)

> "jump in" means: to say something about a subject that another person is already talking about , to join a conversation

I understand the meaning of it.

[From a tutorial](https://youtu.be/PruyW25M4hM?t=48)

> in the next chapters we
> will go deeper into both syntaxes with
> many more examples. **Jumping right in**, a
> simple XPath string we could write in
> Python is given here ...

I guess "Jumping in" is the gerund of "jump in". I don't understand the meaning of it.  Do they pretty much mean the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

The [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/jump-in) offers another meaning that makes a lot more sense in this situation:

> to suddenly become involved in a situation or discussion

In this context, it means to quickly get started with the subject of this chapter.